# Error in using "map" over axios data in store of statically generated Nuxt app

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, static, nuxt.js

In my nuxt app, I have several store actions where I get data via axios. Then I loop over the data with the `map` and do some modifications on the returned array of objects. In the dev mode, it works fine. However, when I generate the static version of the app, I get the error

```
TypeError: h.map is not a function
    at 53f3259.js:formatted:3500
    at v (c554bee.js:2)
    at Generator._invoke (c554bee.js:2)
    at Generator.next (c554bee.js:2)
    at r (c554bee.js:2)
    at l (c554bee.js:2)
```

The code I'm using to define my store actions is the following:

```
  async getParlamenty({ state, commit }) {
    if (state.parlamenty.length) return;
    try {

      let parlamenty = await this.$axios.get('/Api/snemovny/seznam');
      parlamenty = parlamenty.data;

      return Promise.all(parlamenty.map( async (parlament) => {

        parlament.SnemovniObdobi = await this.$axios.get(`/Api/snemovny/${parlament.Id}`);
        parlament.SnemovniObdobi = parlament.SnemovniObdobi.data.SnemovniObdobi;

        return parlament;

      })).then((res) => {
        commit("updateParlamenty", parlamenty);
      });


    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  },
```

Notice I'm using Axios call within the **map** loop, but this shouldn't be the problem as in another action (also causing an error) I do simple string modifications inside the **map** loop:

```
  async getPoslanciSeznam({ state, commit, dispatch }, {limit = 20, stranka = 1, filterCallback = null} ) {
    if (state.poslanci.length) return;
    try {

      let poslanci = await this.$axios.get(`/Api/osoby?limit=${limit}&stranka=${stranka}`).then(res => res.data);

      if (filterCallback !== null) {
        poslanci = poslanci.filter(filterCallback);
      }

      poslanci = poslanci
        .map((poslanec) => {

          if (poslanec.DatumNarozeniZobrazene !== null) {
            poslanec.DatumNarozeniZobrazene = poslanec.DatumNarozeniZobrazene.split('. ')[2];
          }

          if (poslanec.DatumUmrtiZobrazene !== null) {
            poslanec.DatumUmrtiZobrazene = poslanec.DatumUmrtiZobrazene.split('. ')[2];
          }

          return poslanec;

        });

      commit("updatePoslanci", poslanci);
      dispatch('countPoslanciStatistiky');

    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }
```

Is there a well-known issue with doing **map** loop over the variable that has assigned the axios result?

Edit: I believe the error is related to my `Promise.all` code. To paraphrase the code, I am trying to get a list of school classes (`parlamenty`) via Axios and when I get them, I want to get via Axios the list of kids (`snemovniObdobi`) who go to the particular class. Only when all the kids for all school classes are loaded, I want to trigger the Store/Vuex mutation (`update Parlamenty`). There is some cleaning up the data (snemovniObdobi) due to the structure of the database, but that's not relevant, I believe. **The question is: should I return the `Promise.all`?**

Edit 2: I found the issue. The issue was that I was generating statically the Nuxt app without setting the `ssr` to true in the `nuxt.config.js`. I was expecting nuxt to prefetch all the API calls and render them statically if possible. However due to setting `ssr:false`, Nuxt did no prefetch API calls and instead let the client-side do it. However, here I came across other issues, specifically "CORS" issue when fetching API from a dev server. I did not fetch the data and therefore I could not use `Array.map` over them to loop the data, because there was no data prefetched due to the CORS issue.
However, now the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. The issue was that I was generating statically the Nuxt app without setting the ssr to true in the nuxt.config.js. I was expecting nuxt to prefetch all the API calls and render them statically if possible. However due to setting ssr:false, Nuxt did no prefetch API calls and instead let the client-side do it. However, here I came across other issues, specifically "CORS" issue when fetching API from a dev server. I did not fetch the data and therefore I could not use Array.map over them to loop the data, because there was no data prefetched due to the CORS issue. However, now the problem is solved.